# object to json in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

hi guys  i got a problem .
while i was implementing some code  i reached the point that i need to use  toJson method in each object

so inside the class i have added this code

```
public function toJson(){
   return json_encode($this);  // $this which refers to the current object 

}
```

it has returned just `{}` so i knew that it does not recognize the properties of this class 
so instead i have tried to convert it like that

```
public function toJson(){
   $array=(array)$this;
   return json_encode($array);

}
```

i got weird result

```
string '{"\u0000Response\u0000status":0,"\u0000Response\u0000data":null,"\u0000Response\u0000error":" type non valide "}' (length=112)
```

i could eventually write customized json object

like this

```
 public function toJson(){
       $myjson="{field1:data1,field2:data2}";
       return $myjson;

    }
```

but i do not want to return back  to it each time that i add new property

i appreciate if you have any idea about why converting this does not work

Comment: gotta love PHP's idea of namespaces... :-)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to return as a JSON format there? The object's properties?

Comment: @Jefffrey yep, but not mangled with null characters, I assume

Comment: yes im trying to return the whole object  in json format directly from a method named toJson   exactly toString in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the object properties to array before encoding to JSON:

```
public function toJson(){
   return json_encode(get_object_vars($this));
}
```

As you can see, you can use [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) to accomplish that.

Comment: i did explicit  conversion  in the second example (array) $this

Answer (score 1):

This usage works for me with primitives, arrays, associate arrays, and objects:

```
<?php

class Test {
  var $a = "1";
  var $b = array(3, 5, "cat", "monkey");
  var $c = array("animal" => "dromedary");
  public function toJson() {
    return json_encode($this);
  }
}

$test = new Test();
$test->d = new Test();
echo $test->toJson();

?>
```

Running it results in the expected JSON output:

```
$ php test.php 
{"a":"1","b":[3,5,"cat","monkey"],"c":{"animal":"dromedary"},"d":{"a":"1","b":[3,5,"cat","monkey"],"c": {"animal":"dromedary"}}}
```

I'm still running PHP 5.3.15.

Comment: A guy walks into a doctor's office and says, "doc, it hurts if I poke myself here". The doctor replies: "don't do that then". And by this I mean, don't use this method on more complex objects. This works for simple model objects (like beans in the java world).

Comment: for me it does not work but when i use json get_object_vars it works  i do not know why

Comment: Interesting. What PHP version are you on? ($ php --version)

Comment: yea this what i think

Comment: php 5.3.4  and i'm running wamp server in windows xp